# Script takes parameters from the previous run

Tags: linux, bash, asynchronous, docker, alpine-linux

I am using docker container that runs Alpine Linux.It runs some bash script async

```
bash myscript.sh $param1 $param2 &>/dev/null &disown
```

The first time it runs it seems it does nothing it should write to some database but when I run it second time

```
bash myscript.sh $param3 $param4 &>/dev/null &disown
```

It does work but it use parameters from the previous run i.e param1 and param2.

Without `&>/dev/null &disown` it works fine from the first time

Could someone explain to me such behaivour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a delay

```
bash myscript.sh $param1 $param2 &>/dev/null &disown
sleep 1
```

Probably because it async the script finishes too fast
But I would like to hear in depth explanation